# Performing ANOVA on repeated measure in R with random effect

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I organized an experiment wherein participants need to do a task, and they got score for each time they do this task. Each participant needs to do the task 4 times in 4 conditions:

(1) no additional stuff
(2) participants do task while listening to music
(3) participants do task while watching a movie (no sound).
(4) participants do task while listening to the same music and watching the same movie

The lab is small, so I organized participants in group, i.e. 6 people will perform the task in the same time. In total there are 5 groups (30 people).

So I have a dataframe like that

```
subject group music movie score

1 1 0 0 0.5

1 1 1 0 0.3

...

7 2 1 1 0.4
```

My hypothesis is that, either allow watching movie or listening to music will increase score of participants. I want to test against the group effect.

I want to set the subject as random effect not fixed effect, so my idea is the result can be applied for any people, not only recruited people.

I tried with

`df.aov <- aov(score ~ group * music * movie + Error (subject/music + movie), data = df)`

but I am not sure is it the right one, and I am confused by the result of `summary (df.aov)`.

So how should I do the test in R?

Thank you very much

**Update:** Here is the result of `summary (df.aov)`

```
Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
group      4  2.004  0.5010   6.189 0.00132 **
Residuals 25  2.024  0.0809                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: movie
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
movie  1 0.4132  0.4132

Error: subject:music
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
music        1 0.4955  0.4955   13.50 0.00114 **
group:music  4 0.3832  0.0958    2.61 0.05974 . 
Residuals   25 0.9177  0.0367                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Within
                  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
group:movie        4 0.0982  0.0246   1.399   0.2477    
music:movie        1 0.3741  0.3741  21.326 2.74e-05 ***
group:music:movie  4 0.1689  0.0422   2.407   0.0617 .  
Residuals         50 0.8772  0.0175                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```